# Is it a bad idea to encapsulate json in base64 in a xml, to be used in a soap webservice?

Tags: json, xml, web-services, wcf, soap

Basically, I have an webapp that will consume a .net wcf web-service.
I'll be working with a multitude of custom data-types in the web-service, that may vary during the development phase.

To simplify my work here, I thought about creating a single function that would receive 2 parameters:

1. the id of the operation (1-getArticle, 2-getArticlesList, 3-save article details, and so on)
2. the data needed to process the operation (article_id for a search, or a complex json
       data-structure that would be deserialized in the webservice to be
       saved in a database).

To override the problems of escaping special characters like "<" I thought that it would be easier to convert the json to base64 and proceed to decode it in the webapp or in the webservice.

Am I committing a terrible mistake if I choose this path? (json in an xml file, and convert the said json to base64)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're making life far too complex for yourself if you use Base 64. JSON is text. XML is built to handle text.

With a proper library for XML construction such as XOM, JDOM, DOM, etc., you don't need to do any extra work at all. Just shove the JSON text into the right place and the library will escape characters like >, &, and < as needed.

Any legitimate XML parser will unescape this on the other end. As long as you use good libraries, it will all just work without any extra effort or thought on your part.

Comment: Regarding the fact that I am encapsulating json into xml, any comments on that? Is it ok to do that?